# Load a dynamic animation from disk in flutter

Tags: flutter, animation

I am building a flutter application for a donation Kiosk, that would be deployed on tablets that connect to card readers.

I would like the home screen presented to users to contain a custom animation that can be loaded from a disk file (or downloaded) so that we could develop these custom animations for each NGO with ought building separate apps for each case.

The animation should be dynamic, meaning it should be able to take some parameters from the flutter app (ex: number of donations from the last 24h) and change the layout slightly (ex: show a number of trees based on that number).

I found some animation libraries but all of them would mean coding them inside the app, which is not the best scenario for us.

Is this possible? Can you help me by pointing in the right direction :)
Thank you!

Comment: If you want to have custom animations based on parameters "stored in a file" that would require for you to create a "compiler" that would generate the code for the animation, which for basic animations is not that hard. For more complex animations I think it's too complicated. One other option, would be to use Flare  (Rive now) https://rive.app/ to create the animations and just load them like an image :D

Comment: The parameters would come from the application at runtime. Thank you for the Rive recommendation. Looks promising :)
Does it allow for receiving parameters?

Comment: I know you can customise some things about the animation and make it interactionable but not sure how much is supported in flutter.